# Document definition in information retrieval

Tags: terminology, data-mining, information-retrieval

Is there common formal definition of **Document** in information retrieval field? In many researches authors don't define the term **Document**(maybe because it is evident for them). Wikipedia says "text file, document (computer science) a computer file that contains text" but it doesn't seem as common formal definition.

Do you know the common formal definition of **Document**, or, if not, do you know any researches where that term was defined?

Comment: Why do you want a formal definition of **document**? What do you plan to use this definition for? What good would knowing this definition do you? Personally, I don't see why the information retrieval field needs a formal definition of **document**.

Comment: I'm going to make some research in text mining. It's difficult for me to use the term without its definition

Comment: @PeterShor: perhaps because many IR measures (recall precision, ...) are based on the number of relevant/non-relevant/retrieved/... *documents*. Originally a document was synonymous of "unstructured text". Nowadays it is a more general term (it can be a multimedia file, a web page, ...) and you can see it like "unit of information on a particular subject" that can satisfy (or help to satisfy) the information need of the user that queries the IR-system.

Comment: some/many IR methods eg LSA/LSI regard a document as a "set of words [symbol strings separated by space, punctuation etc]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a formal definition of *document* in the Information Retrieval context, you can look at IR glossaries.

A common definition is:

> **Document**:  Specific unit of retrieval (usually text). It can be a web page, an article, a book, a section or chapter.

(see for example the Glossary of the book [Modern Information Retrieval by 
Ricardo Baeza-Yates and Berthier Ribeiro-Neto](http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~hearst/irbook/glossary.html))